# Extract data from ArcMap web map

Tags: maps, wms, arcmap

I would like to extract the underlying data, probably a WMS or WMTS service, from [this map](http://grtgazfrance.maps.arcgis.com/home/webmap/templates/OnePane/basicviewer/embed.html?webmap=c29d48f00d3740b6a654c99f3a8f62c7) of the French gas transmission network (operator GRTgaz).

Sadly it is obfuscated as SVG tiles. Any chance to get to the data?

```
<svg overflow="hidden" width="1917" height="1048" id="map_gc" style="overflow: visible; position: absolute;"><g id="Carte_AGOL_generalise_7504_layer" data-geometry-type="point" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)"><g></g><image fill-opacity="0" stroke="none" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" x="1093" y="278" width="16" height="16" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)"></image> ....
```

Comment: Since an SVG string/file is just HTML with some extras and HTML is almost XML, you can use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to retrieve data from your SVG string. You just need to figure out the logic and structure of your specific SVG and handle data accordingly.

Comment: So without having any clue of XPath - can I really recover the (georeferenced) geometry from this or just SVG paths?

Comment: Well it is not exactly clear what data you do want. The svg seems just to include the orange dots on the map. Also having a georeference will be a rather hard task, mapping the svg coordinates to actual coordinates. If they wanted you to access that data with a program, they probably would have provided an API.

Comment: I think all pipeline operators are secretive about the exact locations of their pipes.